# recoding malloc with mmap strange segfault

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am actually recoding malloc using mmap function, the problem is i am getting a segfault largely before the end of the allocated memory.
I can't find where is the problem in my code.

The init() function is called at the first call of my malloc, then the search_for_free_space() is called instead.

I am allocating 409600 bytes with mmap (100 pages), but the code is getting segfault after using only 26000 bytes without reason.

When i'm multiplying the size of my mmap by 10 the segfault appears later, but i verified that the size given to my mmap is well 409600 and not less.

The segfault should appear only after using all memory as i have not done the next part of the code but it appear too early.

code (you can run it):

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

# define PAGE_SIZE getpagesize()

typedef struct  s_zone
{
    int             size;
    int             free;
    struct s_zone   *next;
}               t_zone;

typedef struct  s_e
{
    t_zone  *tiny;
}               t_e;

static t_e  g_e;

void    *allocate(size_t size)
{
    printf("%s", "allocated memory: ");
    printf("%d\n", (int)size);
    return (mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
        MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANON, -1, 0));
}

void    *init_tiny(size_t size)
{
    g_e.tiny = (t_zone*)allocate((PAGE_SIZE * 100));
    g_e.tiny->size = size;
    g_e.tiny->free = 0;
    g_e.tiny->next = g_e.tiny + sizeof(t_zone) + size;
    g_e.tiny->next->size = PAGE_SIZE;
    g_e.tiny->next->free = 1;
    g_e.tiny->next->next = NULL;
    return (g_e.tiny + sizeof(t_zone));
}

void    *search_for_free_space(size_t size, t_zone *zone)
{
    size_t  i;

    while (zone->free != 1 || zone->size < size)
        zone = zone->next;
    zone->free = 0;
    zone->size = size;
    zone->next = zone + sizeof(t_zone) + size;
    zone->next->size = PAGE_SIZE;
    zone->next->free = 1;
    zone->next->next = NULL;
    return (zone + sizeof(t_zone));
}

void    *malloc2(size_t size)
{
    if (g_e.tiny == NULL)
        return (init_tiny(size));
    else
        return (search_for_free_space(size, g_e.tiny));
    return (NULL);
}

int     main(void)
{
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < 300)
    {
        malloc2(2000);
        i++;
        printf("%s", "used memory: ");
        printf("%d\n", (int)((2000 * i) + (i * sizeof(t_zone))));
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve] for the crash!

Comment: thank you for the comment i added this

Comment: Your debugger should be able to tell you where the segfault happens

Comment: zone + sizeof(t_zone) + size will scale the sizeof() + size value by the size of *zone; I think you want “(t_zone * )((char * )(zone+1)+size)".

Comment: Your algorithm is broken. It's impossible to allocate anything larger than PAGE_SIZE. You need to keep track of available memory and just add new blocks to the end of the list if no free nodes are available. Ditch the "foo->next->size = PAGE_SIZE" logic.

Comment: @Bjorn A. I know i can't allocate more than PAGE_SIZE and it's a normal behavior for my algorithm and what i want as result, this is not my actual problem

Comment: thank you mevets it's working !

Comment: `409600/16 = 25600` (assuming `16 = sizeof(t_zone)`). That should have been your clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mevets pointed out, the problem indeed is

```
zone + sizeof(t_zone) + size;
```

To increase the pointer by `sizeof(t_zone)` bytes when `zone` is of type `t_zone *`, you just add *1*. I.e., `zone + 1`.

Then you need to add *size*  characters to this, i.e.

```
(t_zone *)((char *)(zone + 1) + size)
```

*But* you must also be careful to keep the alignment of the `tzone` structures to their natural alignment; and especially the returned pointers to `_Alignof (max_align_t)`. This would be easiest if the `tzone` is already naturally aligned at the same alignment, or even of the same size as `max_align_t`; and if size is rounded up to the nearest multiple of `max_align_t`.